# Unable to listen to keydown event inside custom directive for mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to bind a directive to some mat-options to get keydown events on them. The directive appears to initialize but doesn't seem to respond to key down events. Any idea why the onKeydown function isn't firing?

Directive

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[appSelectTab]'
    })

    export class SelectTabDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { console.log('init') }

    @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: 
    KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.code.toLowerCase() == "tab"){
       //tab performed on the first option in the select list for example
       //this.el.nativeElement do something to or with me.
    }
    //this doesn't work because the listener is fired for all of the mat-options
}
```

Markup:

```
<mat-option appSelectTab *ngFor="let schedule of maintenanceSchedule" [value]="schedule">
    {{ schedule }}
</mat-option>
```

Additionally, I need the specific mat-option that the keydown event was performed on.

Comment: why do you want a keydown event for option?

Comment: @Supercool I want to do a custom event on certain keydowns

Comment: Hey @Colby Boren did you check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

100% working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-select-change-event-tyhtgk

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectTab]'
})
export class SelectTabDirective {
mouseThere=false;
constructor(private el: ElementRef) { console.log('init in directive') }
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(this.mouseThere && event.code.toLowerCase() == "tab"){
      // console.log(event)
    // console.log(this.el)
    let wholeValue=this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-value').split("-");
    let value=wholeValue[0];
    let i=parseInt(wholeValue[1]);
    console.log(`You pressed tab on ${i+1} option whose value is ${value}`)

    }
}
@HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) mouseEnterHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log("Mouse Enter")
   // console.log(event)
    this.mouseThere=true;
}
@HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) mouseLeaveHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    //console.log("Mouse leave")
    //console.log(event)
   this.mouseThere=false;
}

}
```

Comment: This is close. This gets an event on all the options when I use it. How would you get a the actual option if for example the key pressed was enter on the second option?

Comment: I added a line to the end of my original question, I should have been more clear from the beginning. Sorry.

Comment: How would you get a the actual option ? what do you mean ? the value of matoption??

Comment: yeah, the elementRef would be the option that keydown occurred on. THen you could access any information about that object etc..

Comment: this.el.nativeElement will give you the element right? you can access from there the value and other things?

Comment: I made aditiional edits using some of your code to the original answer that includes comments

Comment: This works only if you are hovering the mouse of the options. This wouldn't be acceptable for the user. I appreciate your help on this issue.

Comment: if you found any solution for your problem , please post it i would like to learn how its done

Answer (score 0):

i think you minus `schedule.(option)` example `[value]="food.value">`. `*ngfor` in maintenanceSchedule. What error happened? or nothing happened

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean, but no error occurs.